# Leaking window apron, need advices for troubleshooting

Tags: windows, leak

We have a window that was installed in 2021 which has been having leaking issue under the apron at center bottom during heavy rains. Hoping to get some advises how to troubleshoot what caused it.

[image]
[image]

Some information: it is a retrofit sliding window at ~90" length, with left and right side sliding towards fixed center (about evenly divided). This window is facing side of the house hence no roof coverage. The leaking area is about 10 inches wide, right under the center apron (you can see from the above image, where the caulking detached from the drywall and the water stain).
[image]

When I check the molding for moisture, it has a much higher reading right above the leaking part:

[image]

But to its left or right, the reading is normal (at least comparing to the rest of the wall). So my assumption is that it wasn't coming from side and drain towards the center.

I did add caulking outside:

[image]

but it didn't help. I have two more suspects:

The tiny gap at the window screen groove towards the center side:

[image: https://imgur.com/I66YVGG]

Poorly designed/cleaned weep holes:

[image]

yes, I admit it has slipped my mind for cleaning.

Is there any advice, anything else worth checking, and what measures I can take to pinpoint the main cause?

Comment: Can you provide interior and exterior pics with a little more context?  It's hard to figure out what's going on with everything zoomed in so tight...

Comment: @Huesmann, thank you for getting back, updated with interior and exterior photos. Let me know if they are good enough

Comment: It seems to me like you may need to do a better job sealing between the vinyl window frame and the black sill/trim.  I can't tell from your pic if the trim has a seam down the length, but I don't see a lot of sealing material there.

Comment: @Huesmann the black piece is actually just decorative framing nailed onto stucco, would that change the likelihood of it being the culprit?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  You need to make sure that the window frame is sealed all the way around.